# List changes of options by week

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

We have a database table that lists option changes this way:

> date     |     option      |      value
>
> 01/07/08 | optionA         | value_a
>
> 01/07/08 | optionB         | value_b
>
> 02/07/08 | optionA         | value_a2

We assume that before the first date that has an option (primary key is date and option) there's no option set. We have to make it so for every day, each option overrides previous changes afterwards, but not backwards.

I would like to know how can I join this table so I can get, for each week, the full set of values latest values per option. Something like the following:

> date     |     option      |      value
>
> 01/07/08 | optionA         | value_a
>
> 01/07/08 | optionB         | value_b
>
> 02/07/08 | optionA         | value_a2
>
> 02/07/08 | optionB         | value_b

Answer (score 0):

Hoping I got your question right

CREATE TABLE test.stack
(
     date DATE
    , option_field VARCHAR(50)
    , value INT(5)
)

TRUNCATE TABLE test.stack;
REPLACE INTO test.stack
VALUES ('08/07/01', 'optionA', 5)
, ('08/07/01', 'optionB', 6)
, ('08/07/02', 'optionA', 11)
, ('08/07/02', 'optionB', 33)
, ('08/07/22', 'optionB', 43)
, ('08/07/24', 'optionB', 235)
, ('08/07/02', 'optionA', 9)
, ('08/07/22', 'optionA', 465)
, ('08/07/24', 'optionA', 421)
;

SELECT ts.date, ts.option_field, ts.value
FROM (
    SELECT s.date, s.option_field, s.value, WEEK(s.date) AS week_no,  MAX(DAYOFMONTH(s.date)) as day_no
    FROM test.stack s
    GROUP BY s.option_field, week_no
) AS ts
;

PS: I have not checked the performance

Answer (score 0):

I would use the group and order functions, something like:

```
select 
week(table1.date), table1.date, table1.option, table1.value
    from
table1
group by week(date) , table1.option
order by date desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the required solution on a secondary channel, so here it is:

```
SELECT
     *
FROM
     days days
     INNER JOIN
     table data
          ON data.date <= days.date 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
     table data2
          ON data2.date  <= weeks.date 
               AND data2.option = data.option
               AND data2.date  > data.date

WHERE
          data2.date IS NULL
```

The table days is one that includes every day for which you need information, i.e. a list of days.

This takes in account every previous day for every day you need to take information (the days on table days) on the first join. The second join searches for accountable days that have more recent information. If there's no more recent information we take that row in account using the `WHERE
    data2.date IS NULL` line.